# How to create a LaTeX table with specific multicolumns and multirows?

Tags: latex, tabular

I'would like to create a table head that looks like this:

[image]

My code so far:

```
\begin{tabular}{| m{4.5cm} | m{2.5cm} | m{2.5cm} | m{1.8cm} | m{1.8cm} |}
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!15} \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Description}  &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Literatur}} \\ \cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Category A} &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Category B} &  {Category C} &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}   \\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Which leads to this:

[image]

I can't figure out why the background color does not fit. If I try to colorize every single cell, the last column is only half visible (vertically).

Comment: Can you make a compilable [mre], including all the necessary packages etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither vertical lines nor background colors are a sign of a professional looking table, see e.g. http://betterposters.blogspot.com/2012/08/the-data-prison.html

However if you insist on such a layout:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,array,hhline}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| m{4.5cm} | m{2.5cm} | m{2.5cm} | m{1.8cm} |}
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!15} \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Description}  &   \\ \hhline{|--->{\arrayrulecolor{gray!15}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|}
\rowcolor{gray!15} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Category A} &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Category B} &  {Category C} &  \multirow{-2}{*}{Literatur}    \\\hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with the `nicematrix` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{m{4.5cm}  m{2.5cm}  m{2.5cm}  m{1.8cm}}[corners,hvlines]
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor{gray!15}{1-2}
\Body
\Block{1-3}{Description}  & & &  \Block{2-1}{Literatur}  \\
Category A & Category B & Category C & \\
test & test & test & test\\
\end{NiceTabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Max Good typography does not get out of fashion :)